# Relaxation of an edge in Dijkstra's algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

What does **`relaxation of an edge`** mean in the context of graph theory ? I came across this while studying up on Dijkstra's algorithm for single source shortest path.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

[Here's](http://www.egr.unlv.edu/~larmore/Courses/CSC269/pathing) a nice description of the Algorithm that also explains the notion of relaxation.

> The notion of "relaxation" comes from an analogy between the estimate
>   of the shortest path and the length of a helical tension spring, which
>   is not designed for compression. Initially, the cost of the shortest
>   path is an overestimate, likened to a stretched out spring. As shorter
>   paths are found, the estimated cost is lowered, and the spring is
>   relaxed. Eventually, the shortest path, if one exists, is found and
>   the spring has been relaxed to its resting length.

Comment: Is there a reason for telling that the EDGE is relaxed, and not the path to the node v. Why "EDGE" relaxation and not "PATH" relaxation

Comment: Makes little sense this explanation. Are springs the edges?  Then what happens to other springs when one is relaxed? Why aren't they all relaxed at the beginning? Or are springs shortest paths? Then they are not compressible beyond what? Why to talk about "relaxing springs" and not "shortening cords"? I've heard that "relaxation" comes from Operations Research, but i cannot yet figure out details...

Comment: This is me again, 4 years later. I [asked](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/3542) elsewhere without getting a satisfactory answer. I now doubt that "relaxation" here has anything to do with *constraint relaxation*, and I seem to get the idea of this answer. Indeed, when nodes are attributed overestimated distances from the source, it is possible to "stretch" (some) edges so that the attributed distances become true distances. Then we can "relax" any "stretched" edge to its "natural" length by updating the attributed distance recorded for its end vertex. This may of course "stretch" other edges.

Answer (score 33):

The relaxation process in Dijkstra's algorithm refers to updating the cost of all vertices  connected to a vertex v, if those costs would be improved by including the path via v.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is about what it means to relax an *edge*.

Answer (score 12):

Relaxing an edge, (a concept you can find in other shortest-path algorithms as well) is trying to lower the cost of getting to a vertex by using another vertex.

You are calculating the distances from a beginning vertex, say *S*, to all the other vertices. At some point, you have intermediate results -- current estimates. The relaxation is the process where you check, for some vertices *u* and *v*:

```
if directly_connected(v, u)
    if est(S, v) > est(S, u) + dist(u,v)
       est(S, v) = est(S, u) + dist(u, v)
```

where `est(S,a)` is the current estimate of the distance, and `dist(a,b)` is the distance between two vertices that are neighbors in the graph.

What you are basically checking in the relaxation process is weather your current estimate from *a* to *b* could be improved by "diverting" the path through *c* (this "diversion" would be the length of a path from *a* to *c* and from *c* to *b*).

Answer (score 3):

## Edge relaxation process

### Initialization

In shortest-path algorithms, a high cost tells the algorithm "do not go down that path". So by default, we only know that the starting node is apart of the shortest path, while all other nodes are still undetermined. Therefore, we assign a low cost of zero to the starting node (e.g. **S**), and a high cost of infinity to every other node (e.g. **A**, **E**).

[image: shortest_path_01]

```golang
S := new Node()
A := new Node()
E := new Node()

// low cost
S.edge_cost = 0

// high cost
A.edge_cost = 1000 // "infinity"
E.edge_cost = 1000 // "infinity"
```

### Relaxation

The high costs are only temporary, and we now need to "relax" reduce the costs. To do that, we use the edge costs (e.g. **a**, **b**, and **c**), and update the nodes if they are lower.

[image: shortest_path_02]

```golang
// Check if S node can be reduced
// SS := S.edge_cost + S.edge_cost // 0 + 0 = 0
// if (S.edge_cost > SS) { // 0 > 0 => false
//   S.edge_cost = SS
// }

// Check if A node can be reduced
SA := S.edge_cost + a // 0 + 3 = 3
if (A.edge_cost > SA) { // 1000 > 3 => true
  A.edge_cost = SA // 3
}

// Check if E node can be reduced
AE := A.edge_cost + b // 3 + 5 = 8
if (E.edge_cost > AE) { // 1000 > 8 => true
  E.edge_cost = AE // 8
}
```

### Relaxation repeated

[image: shortest_path_03]

```golang
// Note: The nodes hold memory,
//  so the `edge_cost` remembers the previous cost,
//  and that's what the edge is compared against

SE := S.edge_cost + c // 0 + 1 = 1
if (E.edge_cost > SE) { // 8 > 1 => true 
  E.edge_cost = SE // 1
}
```

Comment: This seems to be defining what it means to relax a vertex, but it doesn't define what it means to relax an edge.

Comment: @user1142217 - The edges are SA, SE, and AE. As the vertices A and E are relaxed down from infinity, so are the edges.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2E7MmKv0Y24&t=1336s Time: 28:30. Funny thing is that the shortest paths are the ones that are under TENSION. To me this is the exact opposite of RELAX. Oh well.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment yet but let me have a go at answering the comments on the accepted answer.

> user3245268 commented:
>
> Is there a reason for telling that the EDGE is relaxed, and not the
> path to the node v. Why "EDGE" relaxation and not "PATH" relaxation

The reason why typically *edges* are relaxed as opposed to *paths* might be that during the execution of Dijkstra's algorithm, no explicit representation of any path is present; all you have at this stage are the predecessor pointers of each node.

Obviously, if an edge is relaxed, the implicit new shortest path is relaxed as well, so it does not contradict the analogy to relax a path. But in the algorithm, where you don't really think about paths yet, the notion of relaxing an edge on the path instead makes just as much sense in the context.

> Alexey commented:
>
> Makes little sense this explanation. Are springs the edges? Then what happens to other springs when one is relaxed? Why aren't they all relaxed at the beginning? Or are springs shortest paths? Then they are not compressible beyond what? Why to talk about "relaxing springs" and not "shortening cords"? I've heard that "relaxation" comes from Operations Research, but i cannot yet figure out details...

Yes, springs are the edges.

When one spring is relaxed, some "tension" in part of the subgraph may be released and some other springs may relax as well as a result.

At the beginning, the (preliminary) shortest distance from the starting node to any other node is initialized to infinity, so all springs are streched out to infinity.

The springs are supposed to be "not compressible [beyond their resting state]," but I do think that this is rather confusing, and that the alternative "cord model" of a graph is a bit simpler to grasp. Cords can

- be streched to their proper length
- be overstreched beyond their proper length while they are not explored yet or
- just dangle about when they are not part of any shortest path

When relaxing an edge, the edge of the "new shortest path" goes from overstreched to just streched, while the edge of the "old shortest path" goes from streched to loose.

Comment: """When one spring is relaxed, some "tension" in part of the subgraph may be released and some other springs may relax as well as a result.""" -- it is important to note that some may also get stretched as a result of relaxation of another one. (Not in Dijkstra, I think, but in general, if relaxations are performed in an arbitrary order.)

Comment: "At the beginning, the (preliminary) shortest distance from the starting node to any other node is initialized to infinity, so all springs are streched out to infinity." -- it does not look like that: initially, we may consider only the edges from the source as stretched to infinity, while all the others to be at their natural length.

Comment: I think that if $d[u]$ and $d[v]$ are preliminary estimates of the distances or $u$ and $v$ from the source, and $e$ is an edge from $u$ to $v$ of length $\ell(e)$, then $e$ is stretched if and only if $|d[u] - d[v]| >\ell(e)$, and in that case it is stretched by $|d[u] - d[v]| -\ell(e)$.

Answer (score 0):

lets suppose in graph if we have (u,v)∈ E where w(u,v)=10 
then if by adding a third vertex in between them like w(u,y)=1 and w(y,v)=3 now we  find a path between u and v with weight 1+3=4<10. Now we will consider the second path as shortest which is (u,y,v) and will ignore the first one, this is relaxation.

Answer (score 0):

Edge relaxation.

> To relax an edge v -> w means to test whether the best-known way from
>   s to w is to from s to v, then take the edge from v to w, and, if so,
>   update our data structures.

Java code:

```
private void relax(DirectedEdge e) {
    int v = e.from(), w = e.to;
    if (distTo[w] > distTo[v] + e.weight()) {
        distTo[w] = distTo[v] + e.weight();
        edgeTo[w] = e;
    }
}
```

There is also vertex relaxation. That means to relax all the edges pointing from a given vertex.

```
private void relax(EdgeWeightedGraph G, int v) {
    for (DirectedEdge e : G.adj(v)) {
        relax(e);
    }
}
```

From https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/44sp/

Comment: This is not especially clear, but at least, unlike the previous answers, it makes an attempt to answer the question about what it means to relax an *edge*.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my interpretation of the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12782683), as well as of the [demonstration video](https://youtu.be/2E7MmKv0Y24?si=v8bqjhSoPnwwRH3H&t=1835) linked from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71385258).

Imagine that the graph edges are ropes of given lengths.  To get the shortest path distances from the source node to all the other nodes, as well as the shortest paths themselves, it is enough to hold the source node and let the other ones suspend from it vertically on the ropes.  This is a physical solution.  To get an algorithmic solution, however, the physical laws need to be explicitly tested and enforced.

Let now the graph edges be elastically stretchable, with given lengths at rest.

Pin the source node fixed and pin all the other nodes strictly vertically under it at a very large distance (to be considered infinite).  Thus all the edges from the source node to its neighbors are (infinitely) stretched.  (This corresponds to the situation when `d[s] = 0` for the source node `s`, and `d[u]` is infinite for every other node `u`.)

Take now any stretched edge and **relax** it by unpinning and re-pinning its lower end, so that the distance between its ends become equal the the edge's "natural" length at rest.  This operation may relax some other edges as well, or even make them "loose" (with the physical distance between the ends smaller than the edge's "natural" length).  This operation may as well stretch some other edges which were "loose" or "relaxed" before.

If `d[u]` denotes the length of the currently known shortest path from the source `s` to the node `u`, then at this moment `u` is pinned at the distance `d[u]` under `s`.

In this configuration, an edge `e` from `u` to `v` is *stretched* if and only if its ("natural") length is less than the absolute value `|d[u] - d[v]|` (the physical distance between `u` and `v`), *relaxed* if its length equals `|d[u] - d[v]|`, and *loose* if its length is greater than `|d[u] - d[v]|`.