# What is the difference between triangle inequality and path relaxation in Dijkstra's algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dijkstra

The relaxation process in Dijkstra's algorithm refers to updating the cost of all vertices connected to a vertex v from source vertex V.

I think the triangle inequality also refers the same.

Comment: To me they seem more of the opposite: the triangle inequality says that the path `AB` is at most as long as `AC + BC`. Path relaxation of `AB` only happens when `AC + BC < AB`.

Answer (score 2):

Path relaxation is the process by which we arrive at the shortest paths from source to all vertices. [Relaxation of an edge in Dijkstra's algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12782431/relaxation-of-an-edge-in-dijkstras-algorithm)

Triangle inequality refers to the lengths of the shortest paths between the vertices. For example the shortest distance between A and B D(A,B) is not greater than D(A,C) + D(C,B) for any other vertex C not lying in the shortest path from A to B.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but since I'm here I'll add a relevant answer in case it helps someone else...

What happens in the relaxation step of a shortest path algorithm is a move *towards* the shortest path. The algorithm maintains an *estimate* of the shortest path from node *u* to node *v* and corrects itself whenever it detects a shorter path during its walk.

If relaxation occurs that means that a violation of the triangle inequality was detected, and since that can't actually happen then it must mean that the algorithm's estimate is incorrect, so it updates the estimate through relaxation in order to bring the triangle formed by the three paths back into compliance with the triangle inequality.

The algorithm starts with estimates at infinity, and as it progresses, through relaxation these estimates each converge on the correct shortest path for each node.

Answer (score 0):

The two concepts are very similar when you think of 3 nodes involved in the relaxation process as vertices of a triangle.

The key difference, however, is that the triangle inequality is *only* applicable to triangles that can actually be drawn on a 2D surface. Only on such a realistic triangle does the `AB + BC > AC` hold.

When relaxing edges in Dijkstra's algorithm, however, you could have situations where `AB = 3, BC = 3 and AC = 7` i.e. the three nodes `A, B and C` would not actually make a proper triangle if drawn. You could even be working with negative distances in Dijkstra's algorithm.

Thus triangle inequality isn't directly applicable to the relaxation process of Dijkstra's algorithm.