# How should I understand the name of the "relax" operation when computing the shortest path of a graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, dijkstra

My question is just like the title. When calculating the shortest path of a graph, a operation named **relax** is often used. It's easy to under why this operation is used but the meaning of the name is a mystery for me.
What's the meaning of "**relax**"?

Here is the sample of the Dijkstra writing by pseudo-code:

```
DIJKSTRA(G,w,s)
　　1　INITIALIZE-SINGLE-SOURCE(G，s)
　　2　S ← Φ
　　3　Q ← V[G]
　　4　while Q≠Φ
　　5　    do u EXTRACT-MIN(Q)
　　6　    S ← S∪{u}
　　7　    for each vertex v∈Adj[u]
　　8　        do RELAX(u，v，w)
```

And the **relax** is here:

```
RELAX(u,v,w)  
    1  if d[v] > d[u] + w 
          d[v] ← d[u] + w
```

Comment: Can you show a reference to an implementation of the shortest path algorithm with a *relax* statement.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Okay. I've edited my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12782431/relaxation-of-an-edge-in-dijkstras-algorithm

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes, it's a good answer for my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to think about Dijkstra's algorithm is that it's solving a linear program corresponding to the shortest path problem.

```
maximize sum for v in V of d[v]
subject to
d[s] = 0
for each arc u->v, d[v] ≤ d[u] + w[u->v]  (*)
```

Given an assignment of LP variable, we can define the *slack* of each constraint. The meaning of slack is that, when it's zero, the left-hand side of the constraint equals the right, and when it's negative, the constraint is violated. Here, the slack for `(*)` is `d[u] + w[u->v] - d[v]`.

Once we've defined slack, `RELAX` is the procedure that relieves tension (i.e., negative slack) on `(*)`.

Comment: This is a new idea about this problem. I haven't think it that way before. Thanks for answer.

Comment: Should that be minimize rather than maximize?  Also, why do they say relax an edge?  Why not relax the path or something else?  Thanks for your answer.  It helps to think of it in a different way.

Comment: @user650654 The physical analogy for Dijkstra here is that we realize a graph out of weights connected by string, then hold the weight corresponding to the source at depth 0 and let the others fall as far as they can, knowing that the strings on shortest paths will be pulled taut. Maximize represents "fall as far as they can".